# how to get hcaptcha callback function

Tags: javascript

when i try to get hcaptcha callback with hcaptcha.render method i don't get container and params here is my code

```
window.hcaptcha.render = (container, params) => {
                console.log(container)
                console.log(params)
                window.hcaptchaCallback = params.callback
            }
const scriptUrl = new URL(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('script')).filter(s => s.src.includes('https://cloudflare.hcaptcha.com/1/api.js')).map(s => s.src)[0])

window[scriptUrl.searchParams.get('onload')]()
```

the hcaptchacallback function is empty, however when I pause in the code of the page I receive the two elements as well as the filled function. do you have a solution please?

Comment: now i know the name of the function it is hcaptchacallback + Date.now(), do you know how i can retrieve it?

Comment: You say you have the name of the callback function, but there are no details where you or how you found it.. or how did you figure out it was the callback function to begin with? Need more details.